# Create SQL Server Stored Procedure that will get last_Run_DateTime column from ORACLE table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, oracle11g

Is there a way to create stored procedure in sql server that will go to my table in Oracle db and get the last run datetime?

Comment: Yes it is possible, read on "Linked Servers" or "openquery" command

Answer (score 1):

I went with Linked Servers approach.
This article explained exactly what to do step-by-step.

http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/connecting-sql-server-and-oracle-using-linked-servers